# Why making fulltext index on innodb engine throws error?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, ubuntu-14.04

I've a database on my local host contains some tables with innodb engine and there are some fulltext indexes on some columns. All fine and there is no problem. Here is the detail of my localhost:

[image]

And I've exported it and I want to import it on my server. When I import it, it says *"you cannot create fulltext index on innodb engine"*
. Here is the detail of my localhost:

[image]

Does anybody know what's the problem? I suspect the problem comes from MySQL version on the server. Am I right? What should I do now?

Comment: the two environments are different. So i guess that there are some syntax which is different in the databases. MariaDB is a fork of MySQL and not the same so this could be a possible problem  Could you provide us the import query where the database structure is created with the indexes?

Comment: `InnoDB tables support FULLTEXT indexes, starting in MySQL 5.6.4.`. See [14.8.1.7 Limits on InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Comment: @Noob The file I import is about 40MB and I cannot find that part you want.

Comment: @wchiquito Can I update my current version of MySQL on the server?

Comment: You can install newer version of course

Comment: should I uninstall the old version first?